# What is the right way to prove $y= \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ fails the function definition $\forall x\in A,\forall y,z\in B:f(x)=y\land f(x)=z\rightarrow y=z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I'm trying to work out where I'm going wrong.

By definition of a function, if $y = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is a function $f: A \rightarrow B$, then we have $\forall x \in A, \forall y,z \in B: f(x)=y \land f(x)=z \rightarrow y=z$.

I'm trying to show that $y = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ fails to meet this requirement, but it seems to me to imply instead $\forall x \in A: f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} \lor f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$, i.e. I'm getting a logical OR instead of a logical AND, following the fact that $y = \pm z$ implies $y = z$ or $y = -z$.

Any hint or tips on what I could be doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: You exhibit a single value of $x$ that yields two different values for the assignation. E.g., if $x=0$, then both $y=1$ and $z=-1$ satisfy the assignation, but $y\neq z$.

Comment: The negation of $\forall x\in A \forall y,z\in B (f(x)=y\wedge f(x)=z\rightarrow y=z)$ is $\exists x\in A\exists y,z\in B (f(x)=y\wedge f(x)=z\wedge y\neq z)$. So you need to exhibit a single $x$, a single $y$, and a single $z$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry if this is not a smart question, but since $y = \pm z$ implies $y = z \lor y = -z$, don't we have only $f(x) = y \lor f(x) = z$, and not the required $f(x) = y \land f(x) = z$ needed to show the negation?

Comment: Again: the negation is an **existential** statement. In order to prove the existential statement, we just need to **exhibit** *specific* $x$, $y$ and $z$ that satisfy the formula. I gave you **explicit** *specific* values of $x$, $y$ and $z$, and those values satisfy $f(x)=y$, **and** $f(x)=z$ **and** $y\neq z$., Namely, I am saying: $f(0)=1$, $f(0)=-1$, and $1\neq -1$. Which part of that has an "or" in it?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm truly sorry if this is obvious. Suppose I specify $x = 0$. Then $f(x) = 1$ **or** $f(x) = -1$, since $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{x^2 -1}$. Right? We know this since $y = \pm z$ implies $y = z$ or $y = -z$ How come you get $f(x) = 1$ **and** $f(x) = -1$?

Comment: When you write $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (the original things you have, not the one you put in the comment), you are saying that any value which makes the equation true for a given $x$ will be "$f(x)$". In particular, $f(0) = \pm\sqrt{1}$ means that **each** value that makes this equation true "is" $f(0)$. That means that $1$ **is** $f(0)$ (since $1=\pm\sqrt{1}$ *is true*); and that $-1$ **is** $f(0)$ (since $-1=\pm\sqrt{1}$ *is true*). Thus, $f(0)=1$ is true, **and** $f(0)=-1$ is true.

Comment: Your error is in reading what $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ means in this context. It means that a number $a$ is $f(x)$ if and only if either $a=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $a=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Thus, $1=f(0)$ (because the first clause of the disjuction is true), and $-1=f(0)$ (because the second clause of the disjunction is true).

Comment: @shintuku "*By definition of a function*" $-$ What is the definition of a function that you use? The common one is to define a function as a subset of $A \times B$ with the unique value property, and that's usually written as $b=f(a)$. But in the case here $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not an element of $B$, but rather a subset of $B$, so even the notation is incompatible with the definition of a function.

Comment: thank you very much to you both for the comments, I managed to figure it out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a function can be made formal using variable letters, but the OP has to know how to strip away the abstraction when looking at a concrete example. For the relation $y = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$, the OP can write the solution set as a subset of the $(x,y)\text{-plane}$:

$\quad \text{Solution Set}\bigr{[}y = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\bigr{]} = \{(x, \sqrt{1-x^2}) \mid |x| \le 1\} \, \bigcup \, \{(x, -\sqrt{1-x^2}) \mid |x| \le 1\}$

Also, the way this problem is presented we want to show that $y$ can't be expressed as a function of $x$, that writing $\,y = f(x)$ does not work.

So all you need is to find a value of $x$ with $(x,y_1)$ and $(x,y_2)$ in the solution set with $y_1 \ne y_2$.

But

$\quad (0,1) \in \{(x, \sqrt{1-x^2}) \mid |x| \le 1\}$

and

$\quad (0,-1) \in \{(x, -\sqrt{1-x^2}) \mid |x| \le 1\}$

The OP is encouraged to graph the Solution Set in the $(x,y)\text{-plane}$.